# How can I run pytorch with multiple graphic cards?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 4 graphic cards which I want to utilize to pytorch.
I have this net:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 50, 5, 1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4*4*50, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 4*4*50)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

How can I use them on this net?

Comment: You can take a look at the example here: 
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [torch.nn.DataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.DataParallel) to distribute your model among many workers.

Just pass your network (`torch.nn.Module`) to it's constructor and use forward as you would normally. You may also specify on which GPUs it is supposed to run by providing `device_ids` with `List[int]` or `torch.device`.

Just for the sake of code:

```
import torch

# Your network
network = Net()
torch.nn.DataParallel(network)

# Use however you wish
network.forward(data)
```